# How to enable gnome3's brighness control slider in desktop computers

Tags: gnome, display, power-management, brightness, battery

This slider is always visible for laptop and portable computers, probably due to power management settings recognzing the device has a battery to be managed.

[image]

I really want this on my desktop PC. Is there any way to permanently enable it?

Comment: Most external monitors do not allow the OS to control the display's brightness, so it's unlikely that it'll work even if the commands were sent.

Comment: To add to the above, your monitor almost certainly has a brightness control on it. You just need to figure out which button(s) control it.

Comment: Thanks, but not a convincing answer. I can easily control the monitor brightness using `xrandr` or any other software tool available. I'm really just tired of patching up ad-hoc scripts and launcher shortcuts to something that is clearly available in the default shell.

Comment: If you had a chance to test it: Is this feature available in Windows? I'm just curious.

Comment: Sorry. The last Windows I used predates Win10. It's been years since I had it on any computer at home.